# SQL Athena getting the data for the past 12 months

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, date, amazon-athena

I need to grab the data for the past 12 months. I am using SQL within AWS Athena. Below is my code:

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW response_view AS
SELECT
    "cust"."customer_id",
    "cust"."event_triggered_date"
FROM
    (
        db.population_view pop
        INNER JOIN new_db.manual_response_view cust ON ("pop"."customer_id" = "cust"."customer_id")
    )
    WHERE "cust"."event_triggered_date" > current_date - interval '12' month
```

Gives me an error: `cannot be applied to varchar, date`

event_triggered_filed is a string

This is the structure of the date field: `2019-12-04 00:00:00.000`

Comment: That suggests that `event_triggered_date` is being stored as a string.  Fix your data model!

Comment: I appreciate the comment, I would appreciate some help even more - that's why I posted my question on SO.

Comment: What is the structure of  `EVENT_TRIGGERED_DATE`? Could you give us some sample data ? @Chique_Code

Comment: Edited my question with the sample provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

`CAST(EVENT_TRIGGERED_DATE AS DATE)`

OR

`CAST(EVENT_TRIGGERED_DATE AS TIMESTAMP )`

[Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html)

Comment: I have ran your code and the query was successful, however, once I tried to preview the view that I created I had the following error: `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Value cannot be cast to date: 2019-10-17 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Edited my answer please check it. @Chique_Code

Comment: Much appreciated! @Chique_Code

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem I need to get the stating day of the 6th and 12th month from current date.

I have written this, it works for me I hope it will work for other as well.

please refer attached image for query result

```
select current_date as today, date_add('month', -6, (select date(date_format(cast(current_date as date),'%Y-%m-01')))) as Start_of_the_date_6_month_before
```

[image]

For Staring day of the 12 month before date.

```
select current_date as today, date_add('month', -12, (select date(date_format(cast(current_date as date),'%Y-%m-01')))) as Starting_day_of_the_month_12_before
```

Finally i make this changes like this :
[image]

```
With
six_month_And_minus_1_day AS (
select date_add('month', -6, (select date(date_format(cast(current_date as date),'%Y-%m-01')))) as Start_of_the_date_6_month_before,
date_add('day', -1,  date_add('month', -6, (select date(date_format(cast(current_date as date),'%Y-%m-01'))))) as Start_of_the_date_6_month_before_minus_1
)
select * from six_month_And_minus_1_day
```

Any one has better way to do this please suggest.